# Can a pull request on GitHub modify my repository without my permission?

Tags: github

I've been using GitHub to share my projects for while now. Today, I received a notification about a pull request saying that someone added audio to one of the video games that I created. All my files seem to be the same, but I'm scared that someone can modify my repositories without my permission.

My question is: can someone modify my repositories without my permission?

Comment: Please search before asking, and additionally read about what is on-topic.

Comment: While I did VtC, looking closer, the right thing was to edit out the tutorial request. While doing so leaves a poorly researched question (not a close reason), it is a question about a tool (GitHub) which is commonly used for programming. Thus, it's now on-topic.

Comment: Eh, I've looked at it and would still say too broad. How would they be able to? I don't see how OP thinks that's a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

No, if you own the repository and nobody else has 'write' permissions then you decide when and if to merge all "pull requests."

A "pull request" that has not been accepted/merged is *not* part of / in the target repository.

Here's a tutorial from github:
https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request/